# What is the core difference between using of (let) and (const) when we declare of a variable in javascript ES6 (ES2015)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I noticed that the `let` and `const` are similar and behave the same way, but of course there is a reason to create each of them, can you please explain the difference between them with example

Comment: They are not similar at all.  With `const` you declared a variable with a final value, basically. you cannot assign a new value.

Comment: Core difference: `let` is variable while `const` is constant

Comment: Did you look up the documentation of both? They are pretty well documented.

Comment: Great read https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const

Comment: See this :https://wesbos.com/let-vs-const/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similarity between `let` and `const` is that they both have block scope. It means they are only available in the block they are declared.

Difference between them is that variables declared with `let` can be assigned a new value but variables declared with `const` cannot be assigned a new value.

```js
let x = 3;
x = 'changed';

const y = 33;
y = 'changed' //throws error.
```

An important point here is that `const` only prevents assignment to a new value not the modification of variables.

```js
const obj = {a:1};
obj.a = 5 //will not throw error
obj.b = 'something' //will not throw error
obj = {x:1} //will throw error
```

**Note**: If `const` is used to declare a primitive type(string,numbers,symbols,boolean,undefined) it can never be changed.

Comment: "An important point here is that const only prevents assignment to a new value not the modification of variables"....this rule will be only applied for objects and arrays, right?

Comment: @DaniMousa Yes. Arrays are objects.

Comment: @DaniMousa See http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html to make the idea of arrays are object more clear.

Comment: sorry but i have a new enquiry, is ```NaN``` included with the primitive types in the rule above?

Comment: @DaniMousa Yes `NaN` is primitive type and also `null`

Answer (score 1):

when you declare variable with `const` you can't change the value,

```
const name = 'john';
name = 'brad'; // throw error
```

but when you declare variable with `let` you can change it

```
let name = 'john';
name = 'brad';
console.log(name); // brad
```